# Netlogo: express probability to a turtle

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to Netlogo and I'm now stuck with coding this sentence:

**There should be a chance of 10% divided by the total number of turtles that a turtle will hatch a child.**

The initial total number of turtles is 1.

So my code is:

```
let p (0.1 / 1)
    ask n-of (0.1 / 1) turtles 
    [hatch 1]
```

But it seems to me that my code may not be correct. Anyone any ideas how to change it?

I would appreciate any kinds of help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 10% is 0.1, not 0.01.

Comment: Oh sorry my fault, a typo, I will edit it. Perhaps do you have any idea? Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

"ask n-of" is clearly wrong, if there's only one turtle.  And the `random` function only returns integers, so instead of checking for 0.1, let's choose a random number from 0 to 10 times the number of turtles.  Something like this should work.

```
if random 10 < 1 [
  ask one-of turtles
    [hatch 1]
]
```

Here's my justification.  Any given turtle has a 10%/N chance of hatching.  That means that, 10% of the time, one random turtle has a 100% chance.

Say there are 5 turtles.  By the spec, each turtle has a 2% chance of hatching (10%/5).  90% of the time, no one hatches.  In the remaining 10% of the cases, 1 of the 5 will definitely get a chance.  That means each individual turtle's chances are 10% x 20% which is 2%, as the spec says.

That's what the code does.  "random 10" chooses a random number from 0 to 9.  If that number is "< 1" (which means 0), then we choose a turtle at random to hatch.

Comment: Thank you Tim! The initial total number of turtles is 1, but since there will be chances that turtle hatch, so the total number of turtles will increase. Sorry haven't made it explicit. If you have a second, may I ask you why``` random 10*n < n  ```  , how does it mean? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, not entirely clear to me why ```one-of turtles ```? Since I thought that all turtles have chances to hatch

Comment: I'll will expand my answer with my thinking.  And fix what I think is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, put the random chance inside the `ask`

```
ask turtles
[ if random-float 1 < 0.1
  [ hatch 1
  ]
]
```

Part of the problem is that the question is badly expressed. "10% divided by the total number of turtles" doesn't really make sense, so I have interpreted it that approximately 10% of the turtles hatch a child turtle